# Can I break a non-disparagement agreement on my own initiative to aid another in a civil suit?

Tags: contract-law

Suppose a have a non-disparagement agreement with corporation X.  I happen to discover that someone (John) in a different state has filed a class action lawsuit against X.  I have information that may be helpful to John, but John may or may not know that it is there.

Now clearly, from what I read, if they were to ask me for this information during the discovery, I would be able (required in fact) to provide it.    My question is this: Am I allowed to contact John out-of-the-blue and provide him with, or at least direct him towards, this information?

Answer (score 1):

Providing or directing John towards the information would breach the agreement. Even making John aware that you exist may do so.